# Jquery sliders not working together online,but they work fine on offline page

Tags: jquery, debugging, localhost, jquery-ui-slider

The site www.grapho-line.com is using two sliders but only the main slider is working(the one with the big pictures).The thumbnail slider(right below the main jquery slider) is not working as you can see on site.
However both work fine when i run the website on localhost.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Home | Grapho Line Trading LLC</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="slider.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="themes/generic.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="themes/1/slider2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="themes/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="s3Slider.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#slider1').s3Slider({
        timeOut: 5000 
    });
});
</script>
<script src="themes/1/jquery-slider.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi?key=AIzaSyA5m1Nc8ws2BbmPRwKu5gFradvD_hgq6G0" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

google.load("feeds", "1");

function feedLoaded(result) {
  if (!result.error) {
    var container = document.getElementById("homenews3content");
    container.innerHTML = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < result.feed.entries.length; i++) {
      var entry = result.feed.entries[i];
      var div = document.createElement("div");
      div.appendChild(document.createTextNode(entry.title));
      container.appendChild(div);
    }
  }
}

function OnLoad() {
  var feed = new google.feeds.Feed("http://feeds.feedburner.com/KodakNewsReleases.xml");
  feed.includeHistoricalEntries(); // tell the API we want to have old entries too
    feed.setNumEntries(3);
    feed.load(feedLoaded);

}

  google.setOnLoadCallback(OnLoad);
  </script>

<style>

#main{

    background:#fabd2b;
    height:740px;

 }

 </style>




</head>

<body>




<div id="main">
<img src="logonew.png" id="kodaklogo" />
<img src="grapho.png" id="mainbackground"/>



<div id="headmenu">
<ul id="nav">
<li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
<li class="sub"><a href="products.html">PRODUCTS</a>
<ul>
        <li><a href="flexographic&letterpress.html">  &nbsp;Flexographic & Letterpress</a></li>
        <li><a href="offsetctp.html">  &nbsp;Offset CTP</a></li>
        <li><a href="proofing&wideformat.html">  &nbsp;Proofing & Wide Format</a></li>
        <li><a href="brandprotectionsolutions.html">&nbsp;Brand Protection Solutions</a></li>
        <li><a href="enterprisemarketing.html">&nbsp;Enterprise Marketing</a></li>
        <li><a href="productionworkflow.html">&nbsp;Production Workflow Solutions</a></li>
        <li><a href="colormanagement.html">&nbsp;Color Management & Screening</a></li>

 </ul>
 </li>
 <li><a href="aboutus.html">ABOUT US</a></li>
 <li><a href="contactus.html">CONTACT US</a></li>
 </ul>



 </div>

 <div id="slider1">
    <ul id="slider1Content">
        <li class="slider1Image">
            <a href=""><img src="example_images/wide/flexcelnxplate.jpg" alt="1" /></a>
            <span class="left"><strong>KODAK FLEXCEL NX</strong><br /><br />KODAK FLEXCEL NX Plates are an important part of the KODAK FLEXCEL NX System. With the FLEXCEL NX System for the first time you can achieve gravure-class print quality on a wide variety of substrates.</span></li>
        <li class="slider1Image">
            <a href="aboutus.html"><img src="example_images/wide/flexoplates.jpg" alt="2" /></a>
            <span class="left"><strong>KODAK FLEXCEL SR</strong><br /><br />KODAK FLEXCEL SR Flexographic Plates have been designed to bring brand owners confidence that their packaging will be produced reliably and consistently, and to bring printers of packaging materials increased productivity and peace of mind.</span></li>
        <li class="slider1Image">
            <img src="example_images/wide/flexelnx.JPG" alt="3" />
            <span class="left"><strong>KODAK FLEXCEL NX System</strong><br /><br />The KODAK FLEXCEL NX Wide System allows you to take full advantage of the unique benefits that KODAK FLEXCEL NX Plates offer.It utilizes the proven KODAK SQUARESPOT Imaging Technology to deliver exceptional image quality. </span></li>
        <li class="slider1Image">
            <img src="example_images/wide/directengraving.jpg" alt="4" />
            <span class="left"><strong>KODAK FLEXCEL Direct</strong><br /><br />The KODAK FLEXCEL Direct System offers a brand new approach to direct engraving of elastomers for flexographic printing.The FLEXCEL Direct System is ideal for both printers and prepress service providers</span></li>
         <li class="slider1Image">
            <img src="example_images/wide/flexo.jpg" alt="6" />
            <span class="left"><strong>KODAK FLEXCEL NX System</strong><br /><br />YOU CAN with the KODAK FLEXCEL NX System, a complete solution for digital plate making that enables you to push the boundaries of flexo printing.</span></li>   
        <li class="slider1Image">
            <img src="example_images/wide/m800.jpg" alt="5" />
            <span class="left"><strong>KODAK MAGNUS 800</strong><br /><br />The KODAK MAGNUS 800 Platesetter is a reliable 8-page CTP device with advanced automation options, offering exceptional productivity and stability to meet the needs of offset printers.</span></li>



        <div class="clear slider1Image"></div>
    </ul>
 </div>



 <div id="homecenter">

  <div class="div2">
      <div id="mcts1">
        <a href="productionworkflow.html"><img src="images/DigiCap_300x140_695X250.jpg" /></a>
  <a href="brandprotectionsolutions.html">         <img src="images/3-pharma-protection.jpg" /></a>
  <a href="colormanagement.html">        <img src="images/header_spotless_695X250.jpg" /></a>
  <a href="enterprisemarketing.html">            <img src="images/mqdefault.jpg" /></a>
  <a href="products/ctp/prepress.html">            <img src="images/IPM-Hero2_695x210_695X250.jpg" /></a>
  <a href="proofing&wideformat.html">            <img src="images/proofingandwideformat.jpg" /></a>
  <a href="flexographic&letterpress.html">            <img src="images/flexographic.jpg" /></a>
  <a href="products/proofing/kodakmatchprint.html"><img src="images/matchprint_IceCudesLo_695X250.jpg" /></a>
    </div>
 </div>

 <br/><br/>









 <div class="homenews3">
  <b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Latest news from <a href="http://graphics.kodak.com" target="_blank" >Kodak Graphics</a></b><br/><br/>


    <div id="homenews3content">
   </div>

   </div>



   </div>




   </div>
  </body>


   </html>
```

Comment: Please post your code, we can not help without the code and won't go to the site to see it. Please refer to the [faq] and [about] pages.

Comment: Thankyou! i am new to this so didnot knew that. code is added

Comment: Is the opening <blink> some sort of typo?

Comment: Yes i am sorry it is!

Comment: It looks like you're using two slider plugins on the page (Menucool jQuery Slider and s3Slider). I see one instantiation for the s3Slider (for `#slider1`), but I don't see anything that would initialize another instance of it, or instantiate the Menucool plugin

Comment: But it still works when i load the site on local host. what type of initialization is required?

Answer (score 0):

Use a file search to see if the following path is valid:

```
themes/1/
```